# DOS-protection in Apache

Tags: apache, denial-of-service, mod-evasive

We have a small farm of REST-servers that are behind an Apache 2.4 webserver. Apache serves some static resources and proxies REST-calls to the backend. Every now and then we are hit by a DOS-attack (probably from malicious software on Android phones). The attack lasts several hours and fires over 10 requests per second.

I was hoping that Apache could detect such an attack and prevent the requests from reaching our backend servers. I tried mod_evasive but doesn't seem to work.

Is there some other module for Apache that can block malicious clients?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing a new Ubuntu 16 server with Apache 2.4.18 and mod_evasive. Now it all works as expected.

My previous setup used an older Ubuntu 14 and Apache 2.4.8 so maybe that combination was not compatible with mod_evasive.